# "Cannot Resolve Symbol" in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, chisel

I am trying to run scala/chisel code through IntelliJ version 2020.1 using the cloned repository "Chise-template-release".

When I attempt to create a new class I received the "Cannot Resolve Symbol" Error. I have confirmed that the JDK "openjdk-14 java version 14.0.1" through the project structure.

I have confirmed that the Scala 2.12 is compatible with this JDK. I am not sure why I would be getting this error.

I have attached a screenshot of the error I am receiving[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJUr6.png).
Can someone provide more information on what is causing this error?

Comment: Can you post your dependency tree in the IDEA?

Comment: I actually was able to resolve this issue by clicking File>Invalidate Caches/Restart...